# Jquery - Convert string to Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am retrieving a string from Database & this string is an Array.

```
 jq.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Method/",
            success: function () {
               // Sample data     
               var data = "[{                                   
                              name: "Santro",
                              canvas: "1"
                             }, {                                       
                              name: "Tata",
                              canvas: "2"
                           }]";
```

After getting the data by AJAX call, I get the string.

How to convert this string to an Array?

Comment: `JSON.parse(data);` ignoring the errors

Comment: your data is invalid try it here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Tushar How to solve this double quotes issue?

Comment: Is the data coming from server? Add the code. If not then use the \ at the end of the line where string is not completed. Use single quotes for string and double quotes inside

Comment: var data = [{                                   
                              name: "Santro",
                              canvas: "1"
                             }, {                                       
                              name: "Tata",
                              canvas: "2"
                           }];

Comment: Data is coming from sql, it is stored in a column like this :- [{                                   
                              name: "Santro",
                              canvas: "1"
                             }, {                                       
                              name: "Tata",
                              canvas: "2"
                           }]

Comment: You may escape the quotes like.. \"name\" : \"Santro\",

Comment: I get syntax error as :- `Unexpected token r` at `JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: In general if you want to parse it as JSON, you better serialize it from your server in JSON format.
If this is a particular protocol defined by your server, I think you need to write custom code in your client to parse the string data...

Comment: `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` if your json in valid in jsonlint.com it will be work ! @Anup

Comment: @mohsen my data  is `[{ name: "Santro", canvas: "1" }, { name: "Tata", canvas: "2" }]`. When i validate it in jsonlint.com, it shows me error.

Comment: it's not valid! your backend is php? @Anup

Comment: Wait..i will raise another question with more clarity.

Comment: Edit this question, dont raise another one!

Comment: @Anup this is your valid json `[
    {
        "name": "saura",
        "canvas": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "tat",
        "canvas": 3
    }
]` and it will work with `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);`  that it!

Comment: New question :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384841/string-data-conversion-to-array-issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jq.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Method/",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (obj) {
            $.map(obj, function(el) 
               { 
                    return el // as array 
               });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

your php should look like this :

```
 public function actionTest2() {
    $arr[] = [
        'name' => 'saura',
        'canvas' => 1,
    ];
    $arr[] = [
        'name' => 'tat',
        'canvas' => 3,
    ];
  //$arr like your db result 
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

and php output: `[{"name":"saura","canvas":1},{"name":"tat","canvas":3}]`

your js should look like this:

```
jq.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test2",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data) {
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
       console.log(obj[0]); // make loop to navigate the data
    }
```

Comment: check this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384841/string-data-conversion-to-array-issue

Comment: check the answer please is that you want!