# String data conversion to array Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster. Here is  Code for default chart sizes :-

```
$scope.dashboards = {
  '1': {
    widgets: [{
      row: 0,
      col: 0,
      sizeX: 2,
      sizeY: 1,
      name: "Chart1",
      canvas: "canvas1"
    }, {
      row: 0,
      col: 2,
      sizeX: 2,
      sizeY: 1,
      name: "Chart2",
      canvas: "canvas2"
    }]
  }
};
```

I want to store this default sizes in a database & call it on load & apply it to `$scope.dashboards`.

So i stored the data in database column like this :-

`[{row: 0,col: 0,sizeX: 2,sizeY: 1,name: "Chart1",canvas: "canvas1"}, {row: 0,col: 2,sizeX: 2,sizeY: 1,name: "Chart2",canvas: "canvas2"}]`

And after ajax call :-

```
jq.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Method/",
    success: function(data) {

        var arr = JSON.parse(data);

        $scope.dashboards = {
            '1': {
                widgets: arr
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Gives me error :-

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token r
    at Object.parse (native)
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse() is very strict in grammer,as the pair of menber of an object,it should be

string:value
, so the "first" and "second" should be string as json. change your json to following code and it should be right

```
'[{"row": "0","col": "0","sizeX": "2","sizeY": "1","name": "Chart1","canvas": "canvas1"},
  {"row": 0,"col": 2,"sizeX": 2,"sizeY": 1,"name": "Chart2","canvas": "canvas2"}]
```

it will work
this question is answered before

or add

dataType:"json" to your function
 in case you will need not to parse this object

```
jq.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Method/",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data) {

        var arr = data;

        $scope.dashboards = {
            '1': {
                widgets: arr
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like ajax intelligent guess already treats data as a json and transforms it into an object, so you don't have to parse it once again. This statement: `var arr = JSON.parse(data);` is redundant. Try:

```
jq.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Method/",
    success: function (data) {        
        $scope.dashboards = {
            '1': {
                widgets: data
             }
        };
    }
});
```